# Passing Activity Object to non-Activity class in android

Tags: android

I have a object from Activity class like this:

```
 CustomPaint customCanvasPaint=(CustomPaint) dialog.findViewById(R.id.customCanvasPaint);
```

how to pass this object to class like this:

```
public class CustomPaint extends CanvasView {
  public CustomPaint(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize(context);
  }

  public CustomPaint(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize(context);
  }


  public void initialize(Context context){
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_paint,null);
    CanvasView canvasView = (CanvasView) view.findViewById(R.id.customCanvasView);
    canvasView.setPaintStrokeColor(Color.RED);
    canvasView.setPaintStrokeWidth(12f);
  }
}
```

I want customize object in initialize method but paint Color and paint Width don't change.
how to i do it ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomPaint extends CanvasView {
 CanvasView mCanvasView;
 public CustomPaint(Context context,CanvasView canvasView) {
    super(context);
    this.mCanvasView = canvasView;
    initialize(context);
  }

  public CustomPaint(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,CanvasView canvasView) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.mCanvasView = canvasView;
    initialize(context);
  }

public void initialize(Context context){

canvasView.setPaintStrokeColor(Color.RED);
canvasView.setPaintStrokeWidth(12f);
 }
  }
```

And Form Activity

```
 CanvasView canvasPaint=(CanvasView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.canvasPaint);
CustomPaint mCustomPaint = new CustomPaint(this,canvasPaint);
```

Comment: Object from CustomPaint  class is not the CanvasView

Answer (score 0):

You can make required changes in your subclass and add this subclass into your .xml layout file.

```
 CustomPaint canvasPaint=(CustomPaint) dialog.findViewById(R.id.customPaint);
```

In order to make changes to this view, you should override `onDraw()` method of draw whatever you want on passed canvas to onDraw() method. Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an object by creating a setter method in your class:

This is your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   // 

   CustomPaint view = (CustomPaint) findViewById(R.id.customPaint);
   MyObject object = new MyObject("This is a test object");
   view.setData(object);
   view.postInvalidate();
}
```

And from your custom class:

```
public CustomPaint extends View {
   private MyObject mData;

   //... Constructor and others ... 

   public void setData(MyObject data) {
      mData = data;
   }
}
```

Comment: I want create a CustomPaint while Put all the code in the non-activity class